# How can i achieve pstree -sup $$ just with ps?

Tags: linux, command-line, ps

how can i achieve `pstree -sup $$` just using ps?
Tried `ps h -a -o  pid,user,comm= $$` but can't figure it out, 
how to get the "process-chain"... Do I need a shell-script for it?

Thx
Johnny

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

PID=$(ps -h -o pid $1)
while true;do
    user=$(ps h -o user $PID)    
    cmd=$(ps h -o comm= $PID) 
    echo -e "$PID \t  ($cmd,$user)"
    [ $PID != 1 ] || break  
    PID=$(ps h -o ppid $PID);
done;
exit 0
```

Comment: A bit of comments, explanations will make this answer much better